# leaflet map with brown lines in squares

Tags: symfony, leaflet

I would like to avoid the brown lines in square on my leaflet map. My first leaflet map works perfectly as it is in a div in the block body of my project in symfony. The second one is in the following code :

```
{% block body %}

    <div class="siteTemplate">
        <div class="titreTemplate">
            <h1>Sites</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href='https://fr.freepik.com/photos/nuage'>Nuage photo créé par wirestock - fr.freepik.com</a>

    {% dump(media) %}


    <section id="tabs" class="tab-container">
        <div>
            <h2>Site de {{ site.nom }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="onglets">
                <a href="#" class="actif" class="col-4" class="tabA">Détail</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-4" class="tabA">Photo</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-4" class="tabA">Carte</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            {% for image in site.media %}
                <div class="panelImg">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/' ~ image )}}" alt="Image" width="150px" heigth="160">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            
            <section class="carte_panel">
                <!-- Ici s'affichera la carte -->
                <div id="macarte2"></div>
            </section>
        
        </div>
    </section>
```

The map is in the third panel.
In CSS I have the following code :

```
/** tabs **/

        .tab-container {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: 20px 0;
            /* border: 2px solid black; */
        }

        .tab-container .onglets {
            background-color: rgba(100, 161, 157, 0.5);
            display: flex;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            /* border:2px solid black; */
        }

        .onglets {
            background-color: rgba(100, 161, 157, 0.5);
            display: flex;
            height: 70px;
            line-height: 500px;
            /* border:2px solid black; */
        }

        .tab-container .onglets a {
            flex: 1;
            border: 1px solid rgba(100, 161, 157, 1);
            border-bottom: none;
            color: #317133;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .tab-container .panel {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #144c7448;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid rgba(100, 161, 157, 1);
        }

        .tab-container .onglets a.actif {
            background-color: rgba(100, 161, 157, 1);
            color: #fff;
        }

        .tab-container .panel img {
            max-width: 94%;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

And I have just a little CSS for the map :

```
 #macarte2 {
                height: 450px;
                margin: 20px;
            }
```

And the map is like that :
[image]

Comment: The code you have posted wasn't enough for me to reproduce the problem in a static web page (I'm not using Symfony), but it looks like your map tile images are inheriting some CSS from your panel layout, possibly affecting their margins, padding or image size. You should be able to use your browser's developer tools to debug the problem: in Chrome or Firefox, right-click on a map tile and choose 'Inspect'.  You should be able to turn on or off CSS rules until you find which are causing the problem, then set more specific rules for descendants of `#macarte2` to override them.

Comment: hi, I discovered that this is when I delete the following bootstrap code that the map is well working : *, ::after, ::before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }   but I tried to affect it to the class .carte_panel in whitch is the map, but it didn't worked. Otherwise, it's breaking all bootstrap CSS. I think I still don't understand the meaning of that bootstrap css